# List out the .txt files which I modified in the previous five minutes

Tags: powershell, filter, match

I managed to list out all the files which I modified in the last 5 minutes, but I only need the modified txt files. How can I get that?

Here is my code:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse| where-object{$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5)}
```

I know I should use `-match`, but I don't know where to put it and how to use it properly.

Comment: Use `Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6

has an example part way down that has `-Path *.txt` (and it also has an `-Include *.txt -Exclude A*` if you want examples of how to be more specific) - try those

As these things are options of `Get-ChildItem` they should go just before/after the `-Recurse`, i.e. before the pipe `|`